# SAM file to FASTA with awk or sed?

Tags: awk, sed, bioinformatics, fasta

An example of a sam file is here:

```
@SQ SN:gi|669687444|gb|KJ769480.1|  LN:1200
@SQ SN:gi|669687442|gb|KJ769479.1|  LN:900
@SQ SN:gi|669687440|gb|KJ769478.1|  LN:1162
@SQ SN:gi|669687438|gb|KJ769477.1|  LN:1074
@SQ SN:gi|669687436|gb|KJ769476.1|  LN:1194
@SQ SN:gi|669687434|gb|KJ769475.1|  LN:1074
@SQ SN:gi|669687432|gb|KJ769474.1|  LN:1194
@SQ SN:gi|669687430|gb|KJ769473.1|  LN:1074
@SQ SN:gi|669687428|gb|KJ769472.1|  LN:1194
@SQ SN:gi|669687426|gb|KJ769471.1|  LN:1189
@SQ SN:gi|669687424|gb|KJ769470.1|  LN:1074
@SQ SN:gi|669687422|gb|KJ769469.1|  LN:370
@PG ID:bwa  PN:bwa  VN:0.7.10-r789  CL:bwa mem /ibers/ernie/home/thh32/Scratch/Hidden_virome/Against_NCBI_viral/Sweetspot/bwa_NCBI_viral_nucl test.fa
Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:3636:2018  4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   AAACCATTCGCTTCCTTTAAATCTATCTGTTATTTCCCTTAAATAATTTGAACCATGCGAAGCAATATAAGGATTTAAGACGAAACAATTCTTTTCTCT *   AS:i:0  XS:i:0
Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:3508:2062  4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   TCGCTATGCTTACTCCAATGTGGCGTACCAGTGTGCGAAGCTGATGCGCAAACCACGGGAAAAGGAGAAACTCTATCGGTGGATCGTGGATATGGAATTCAAATCCGGTGAGATCCC   *   AS:i:0  XS:i:0
Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:1470:2237  4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GCGGAGCATATCCCCTTGCGTCCTGGACGGCGTGCCCGCATTCATGGGCGGCCACGGCCGCAGCTGCGATGGAATTCATCCCATACACGCTTTCTGAAAGGTTTACGGTCTTGCTCCTGGGATCG   *   AS:i:0  XS:i:0
Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:1540:2114  4   *   0   0   *   *   0   0   GCGCGCAAGGTCCCGCGGATACTGGTCTGCCATATCTCCAACCCGCCCCTTAAGCGTGATGACGAAATGATCTACCCGAAAAGCTCAGCCGGGTTCCATCCCGGCAACGACGCGCCGCG *   AS:i:0  XS:i:0
```

Wanted output is:

```
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:7988:2027 
GCCATCTCCAACCTCACCACCGGTAGCGGCAACCAGATGAGCTACAACCTCATCGCCATCCTTTGCGGCTTGATCGCCATGGCCGTCACCGCAATCTGCGCTCACTACGGCAAAAAGACCGTCAGCTTAATCCCATTCGTCCTTGGCATGTGCGCCGGTTATGTCGCGGCC
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:6459:2053 
TCACCACTTATTGCATCACCATACACATCAGTTACTGTGATTGTTACTGTGATGTTACCATCGATAGAGGGGTTATAATCTGAACATTCAATGTTTGGTATACTTGTGCTTAACAAAGTAACATCAGATTTCAATGTGTCAATTCTGCTATCCCCTGTTTGAGTATTACTCCCCCAAACCT
CTGTATTCAAGTTACTAATCTTCGGTGTGACATCTCTGCTAATCACACTTGCCACA
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:7962:2142
CGGTCCACCGAGAAAGGATGCTCCCTCAAAGCCTCAGATAGCGAAGGTGGAGACAGGACAAAAGAAGAAACCCCCCCCCCCACCCCCCCCC
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:8018:2112 
GTGAAACGCCTCGCCGACTCTCTCCGCCACCCGGTAATAGCCGTGGGTGTACGGATCAAACGCAATGGCGTCCACAAGAGACATATCGACCTTGTCACCGGCCATGACGCGCTCGTCTGCCGTGACATTGACGACCTTGCCGATGACGCCGAC
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:2807:2211 
TGAAAGTTGACATAGGAACCTGTGGAAGCATTGTAGTTAATGAGCGTTTTTTTTAAGTCATCAAAGTTATTTTTTAAGTTATGACGGCGGATATAATCCTGGAACTTGGGATTGACTATCCATTTATCAAAACACTGATCAAGAACAGTGCTTTGAATAAGCTCAGGTGAAGCATTGACTT
CAAATCCTGGCATAACACCTACAAGATAGCCATATTTCTCAAGTAATGCCT
```

I have never used sed or awk before and am really confused by how they work so if someone could explain how to do this that would be amazing.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: Updated the question to give an example of fatsa output

Comment: If SAM and FASTA are standard formats, then it is likely that there are already tools to do this. It's possibly worth taking a look at [BioPerl](http://www.bioperl.org/wiki/HOWTO:Beginners), which might have something useful built-in.

Comment: The issue is that I want to pipe out of a program which is creating the samfile but dont have the space to store it so need to convert to fasta straight away

Comment: If you can make it explicitly clear how one maps to the other (the formats look quite opaque to me), it may be possible to do this. At the moment, I don't see how your input and output correspond to one another (do they?).

Comment: Ok the info of use from the sam file is eahc items name  such as Rank10_clean_2213 and then on the next line the sequence itself AAACCATTCGCTTCCTTTAAATCTATCTGTTATTTCCCTTAAATAATTTGAACCATGCGAAGCAATATAAGGATTTAAGACGAAACAATTCTTTTCTCT. Creating the output on the first line of >Rank10_clean_2213 and second line of AAACCATTCGCTTCCTTTAAATCTATCTGTTATTTCCCTTAAATAATTTGAACCATGCGAAGCAATATAAGGATTTAAGACGAAACAATTCTTTTCTCT

Comment: Edit your question to show some minimal sample input and the corresponding output in the desired format.

Comment: Updated to show the output to be exactly what should come out.

Comment: Your output and input are derived from different data, judged by the numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the lines starting with `@` using `sed d` like this: `sed '/^@/d'` The `d` stands for delete and the part between slashes is the regex to match (i.e. the beginning of a line `^` followed by `@`). Then just format the other lines using a replacement like this: `sed 's/^\([^ ]*\)[^ATGC]*\([ATGC]*\)[ :*a-zA-Z0-9]*$/>\1\n\2/'`. This command will paste a newline before a sequence of A, T, G or Cs. And adds a `>` in front of the original line. Parts between `\(\)` are captured groups which can be substituted using `\1` or `\2` depending the index of the captured group. The sed command will look for the beginning of a line followed by a number of non spaces (i.e. the odd lines of your output). Then, starting at the next space it will look for a number of non AGTC chars until a string of AGTC occurs. We'll catch this sequence in a group (group 2). After this sequence there can be a number of spaces, alphabetical chars and whatnot (`[ :*a-zA-Z0-9]`) until the end of the line has been matched `$`. We now only take the first group and the second group and paste a newline in between them `/\1\n\2/`.

All you have to do now is insert the maxscore data etc. I can't seem to find where you get this info from.

Say the input is in a file called `sam`:

```
$ sed '/^@/d; s/^\([^ ]*\)[^ATGC]*\([ATGC]*\)[ :*a-zA-Z0-9]*$/>\1\n\2/' sam
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:3636:2018
AAACCATTCGCTTCCTTTAAATCTATCTGTTATTTCCCTTAAATAATTTGAACCATGCGAAGCAATATAAGGATTTAAGACGAAACAATTCTTTTCTCT
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:3508:2062
TCGCTATGCTTACTCCAATGTGGCGTACCAGTGTGCGAAGCTGATGCGCAAACCACGGGAAAAGGAGAAACTCTATCGGTGGATCGTGGATATGGAATTCAAATCCGGTGAGATCCC
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:1470:2237
GCGGAGCATATCCCCTTGCGTCCTGGACGGCGTGCCCGCATTCATGGGCGGCCACGGCCGCAGCTGCGATGGAATTCATCCCATACACGCTTTCTGAAAGGTTTACGGTCTTGCTCCTGGGATCG
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:1540:2114
GCGCGCAAGGTCCCGCGGATACTGGTCTGCCATATCTCCAACCCGCCCCTTAAGCGTGATGACGAAATGATCTACCCGAAAAGCTCAGCCGGGTTCCATCCCGGCAACGACGCGCCGCG
```

Comment: Thanks for this but when I use the code this is the given output: >Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:13998:2091 4 * 0 0 * * 0 0 CAGCATTATCTGATGAGAATGTAACCAAGTGGGCTTTCAACGCTTCCTTTGAGCGAATTTGTCTCTCCAACTGGCTGAAGAAACATCGCCCGGAATACTTCACCGGCTACAGCATCCCGGAGGATCCCGCCGGTCAGTACCTGAATCCGGCATCCTGGAAATGTACCATGATCTGGTCAGCCTATATGGGACTGCCGCTCTCTCTGGAAGGTGTCGGAACCGTCC * AS:i:0 XS:i:

Comment: Same error is occuring with : >Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:13998:2091 4 * 0 0 * * 0 0 CAGCATTATCTGATGAGAATGTAACCAAGTGGGCTTTCAACGCTTCCTTTGAGCGAATTTGTCTCTCCAACTGGCTGAAGAAACATCGCCCGGAATACTTCACCGGCTACAGCATCCCGGAGGATCCCGCCGGTCAGTACCTGAATCCGGCATCCTGGAAATGTACCATGATCTGGTCAGCCTATATGGGACTGCCGCTCTCTCTGGAAGGTGTCGGAACCGTCC * AS:i:0 XS:i:0

Comment: This line is not present in your sample input, can you add the malicious line? Do you experience problems with your supplied input? It's strange because it works on my system and your input...

Answer (score 2):

solution with awk

```
awk '/^@/{ next; } { print ">"$1; print $10 }' input.sam
```

you get

```
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:3636:2018
AAACCATTCGCTTCCTTTAAATCTATCTGTTATTTCCCTTAAATAATTTGAACCATGCGAAGCAATATAAGGATTTAAGACGAAACAATTCTTTTCTCT
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:3508:2062
TCGCTATGCTTACTCCAATGTGGCGTACCAGTGTGCGAAGCTGATGCGCAAACCACGGGAAAAGGAGAAACTCTATCGGTGGATCGTGGATATGGAATTCAAATCCGGTGAGATCCC
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:1470:2237
GCGGAGCATATCCCCTTGCGTCCTGGACGGCGTGCCCGCATTCATGGGCGGCCACGGCCGCAGCTGCGATGGAATTCATCCCATACACGCTTTCTGAAAGGTTTACGGTCTTGCTCCTGGGATCG
>Rank10_clean_2213:4:1101:1540:2114
GCGCGCAAGGTCCCGCGGATACTGGTCTGCCATATCTCCAACCCGCCCCTTAAGCGTGATGACGAAATGATCTACCCGAAAAGCTCAGCCGGGTTCCATCCCGGCAACGACGCGCCGCG
```

from documentation [sam format](https://samtools.github.io/hts-specs/SAMv1.pdf), if you have flag 8 in second column is unmaped sequence, it is better

```
awk '/^@/{ next; } 
    { if(and(int($2),8)){ 
        next; 
      } 
      print ">"$1; 
      print $10 }' input.sam
```

or

```
awk '/^@/{ next; } and(int($2),8){next;} { print ">"$1; print $10 }' input.sam
```